# Documentation or API method for `option_id` information, for the `/flags/options` API calls?

Tags: feature-request, api, api-v2.2, documentation, flags

The Stack Exchange API has a couple of calls that return a list of [`flag_option`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/flag-option) objects.

These objects contain a couple of properties that can be used to identify the flag you need.
For example, when I want to cast a *spam* flag from an app, I used to look for a flag option with an `title` equal to `"spam"`:

```
{"has_flagged":false,"option_id":46534,"title":"spam"},
```

This approach went down the drain when a user tried to cast a flag on a non-English SE site, since their flag options look a little different:

```
{"has_flagged":false,"option_id":46534,"title":"contenido no deseado"},
```

Now, the `option_id` is something else I can identify the proper option from, but these aren't documented anywhere (that I know of).

I'd rather not rely on my own interpretation of these ids from a couple of API calls, since mistakes in flagging just aren't acceptable.

---

<strike>TL;DR: Can these `option_id`s be documented on the [`flag_options`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/flag-option) page, or in an answer here?</strike>

Even these flag Ids aren't stable, and could change at any time.

---

### Feature Request:

Please add an API route that tells me what `option_id` is used for what type of flag, for a specific site. (Where "type of flag" is a *constant*):

A call that'd return something like this:

```
{
    site: 'siteName',
    flag_options:{
        spam: x,
        rude_abusive: y,
        not_an_answer: z,
        <...>
    }
}
```

Comment: The option_id for spam seems stable across all sites. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288216/are-option-ids-for-flags-guaranteed-to-not-change

Comment: @AwesomePoodles: Thanks for the link. That answer also states that the options aren't exactly stable. That would mean there's no _proper, secure_ way to identify a "vlq" flag, for example...

Comment: You could ask for the output of Transifex for the word spam of all localizations?

Answer (score 4):

The original intent of these options is clearly *not* to enable automated flagging, but rather to allow an application to generate a UI that presents the applicable options to a user who would be expected to understand them.

With that in mind, the only safe way to identify a flag is by using an exact string match: one that takes into account the terms used for each flag in various translations.

Yes, this has the potential to fail if we rename (or re-translate) a particular option. But, **it will fail by not finding an applicable flag rather than by finding the wrong one.** Since you already need to handle this outcome for cases where a given post cannot be flagged (already deleted, etc.), your application should thus be able to avoid causing problems.

Comment: Could we get the "Feature Request" part of the (revised) question?  Trying to keep up with constantly changing translations is a poor way to live. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The official documentation is [here](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/flag-option):

> Available flags vary from object to object, user to user, and site to site. An application should not assume that particular flags are always available, or that particular option_ids are stable.

Which isn't great. You *may* be able to get away with it, but there's nothing saying the option IDs can't change out from under you at any time.

Comment: Yea, I was hoping there was something more permanent out there somewhere. Maybe there should be a API method to get flag options types...

Answer (score 2):

Flag options are returned in a list `items` which is ordered in the same way as flag options in the web interface. If the list has one item, it's the mod-attention flag on a deleted post. Otherwise:

- `items[0]` is Spam
- `items[1]` is Rude/Abusive

For Answers:

- `items[2]` is Not An Answer
- `items[3]` is VLQ if the list has 5 items, or mod attention if it has 4.
- `items[4]`, if it exists, is mod attention

For Questions (assuming user has at least 50 rep):

- `items[2]` is Should be Closed
- `items[3]` is a Duplicate
- `items[4]` is VLQ if the list has 6 items, or mod attention if it has 5
- `items[5]`, if it exists, is mod attention

Users under 50 rep do not have the Close and Duplicate flag options.

Comment: Unless a post has been deleted, then `items[0]` can be _"Requires moderator intervention"_. We can't really rely on their order.

Comment: True; but the length of the list would indicate that.

Comment: And that's what I don't want to rely on. The more variables, (order, list length), the more possibility there is for the wrong flag to be applied.