# What are the top level question & answer localized flag_option titles?

Tags: discussion, api, api-v2.2, documentation, flags

For the SE API, the endpoints dealing with flags (e.g. [`/questions/{id}/flags/options`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/question-flag-options)) return the [`flag_option`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/flag-option) type. However, the [`option_id` values are explicitly stated as being unstable](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/flag-option), but it's necessary to determine the `option_id` that is assigned to the flag in order to use any of the `/flags/add` endpoints.

To determine which `option_id` to use, some other property of the `flag_option` must be checked to see if it matches the flag type desired. Unfortunately, the `title` and `description` are localized, so are not the same across all sites.

What are the localized values that are used for the `title`, and on which sites are they localized?

Comment: We really need to push for [this feature request](https://stackapps.com/questions/7491/documentation-or-api-method-for-option-id-information-for-the-flags-options), rather than trying to stand on the shifting sands of whatever today's phrase translation is.

Comment: @BrockAdams I *strongly* agree with that, but it's, at best, 6–8 somethings from now. I consider having to match the localized strings to a list hard-coded in the app/script to be a kludge. However, it's the currently available path to functionality when you're not displaying the `title`/` dialog_title` and `description` to the user for selection. This Q&A is here because I was frustrated by not finding this information anywhere, other than in the responses from the SE API. My hope is that these might save someone the time of determining what all the `title` strings are.

Comment: Admirable, but there is a possibly better kludge IMO.  That is: the most important/core flag id's -- though not stable from release to release -- *are* stable across sites for a given release.  That is, for a given "release"/build of StackExchange, the spam flag has a fixed set of values (or a single common value), etc

Comment: @BrockAdams While the `option_id` numbers may be stable over a considerable time, the documentation explicitly states that their stability should not be relied upon. As [Shog9 has said](https://stackapps.com/a/7494/29529), and I agree with, doing a match to the text of the `title` is more likely to fail-safe than using the numeric `option_id`.

Comment: Not if you verify that id as needed (which would be: (1) rarely, (2) only upon build changes, and (automatable)). That guards against both Id and translation changes.  I may write up this approach, but I want to make a tool for it first and both are low priority for me.

Answer (score 2):

The values for the question and answer `flag_option` `title` properties, which I've determined experimentally, are:

```js
const flagTypes = {
    /* Localizations:
     *   English (not localized)
     *   Japanese: ja.stackoverflow.com
     *   Spanish: es.stackoverflow.com
     *   Portuguese: pt.stackoverflow.com
     *   Russian: ru.stackoverflow.com & rus.stackexchange.com (Русский язык)
     */
    spam: [
        'spam', // English & Portuguese
        'スパム', // Japanese
        'contenido no deseado', // Spanish
        'спам', // Russian
    ],
    rude: [
        'rude or abusive', // English
        '失礼又は暴言', // Japanese
        'rude ou abusivo', // Portuguese
        'невежливый или оскорбительный', // Russian
        'irrespetuoso o abusivo', // Spanish
    ],
    naa: [
        'not an answer', // English
        '回答になっていません', // Japanese
        'não é uma resposta', // Portuguese
        'не является ответом', // Russian
        'no es una respuesta', // Spanish
    ],
    vlq: [
        'very low quality', // English
        '品質が低すぎる', // Japanese
        'qualidade muito baixa', // Portuguese
        'необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством', // Russian
        'muy baja calidad', // Spanish
    ],
    moderator: [
        'in need of moderator intervention', // English
        'モデレーターによる対応が必要です', // Japanese
        'precisa de atenção dos moderadores', // Portuguese
        'требуется вмешательство модератора', // Russian
        'se necesita la intervención de un moderador', // Spanish
    ],
    close: [
        'should be closed...', // English
        'クローズする必要があります', // Japanese
        'deveria ser fechada...', // Portuguese
        'должен быть закрыт...', // Russian
        'debería ser cerrada...', // Spanish
    ],
    duplicate: [
        'a duplicate...', // English
        '重複しています', // Japanese
        'repetida...', // Portuguese
        'дубликат...', // Russian
        'un duplicado...', // Spanish
    ],
};
```

Both the `close` and `duplicate` `flag_option` types contain `sub_options`, which vary from site to site.

These are valid as of the time/date this answer was posted, but there's nothing that requires the SE API to not change these titles. Given that the comment flags have recently been changed, more than once, it's not that unlikely that these will be changed also.

Comment: Upvoted, but this could use an auto-update feature, and hosting somewhere (EG: GitHub) in machine readable (JSON, XML, etc.) form.  Otherwise this answer will be useless in X weeks...